# supress warnings: dead code and conditional compilation

Tags: android, conditional-compilation, dead-code

I often declare some constants to conditionally compile/not compile chunks of code. I put these constants on one class, then I use them all along the (big) app code.

Conf.java

```
    public static final int GUI_ACTIONBAR_HEIGHT=0;
```

elsewhere (example):

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState, Conf.GUI_ACTIONBAR_HEIGHT==0?R.layout.activity_funq_play_noactionbar:R.layout.activity_funq_play, true);
```

However, this triggers a warning "`comparing identical expressions`" in the case shown. It's obviously something I can live with, but I'd like to know if there's any `SupressWarning` magic to get rid of it (and the yellow warning icon in the sourcecode).

```
@SupressWarnings ("unused")
```

doesnt't do the trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a Java compilation warning and toggling it on/off really depends on the IDE. Assuming you are using Eclipse, you can navigate to the configurations by `Preferences > Java > Compiler > Errors/Warning > Comparing identical values ('x==x') 'ignore'` This should turn it off.

Answer (score 0):

An ugly workaround that works in non static methods:

1. Replace the static `MyClass.CONSTANT` access by a `this.CONSTANT` access.
2. You will then have instead one *"The static field MyClass.CONSTANT should be accessed in a static way"* warning.
3. This warning can be suppressed with a `@SuppressWarnings("static-access")` and no more comparison warning.

In your example this gives:

```
@SuppressWarnings("static-access")
public void onCreate(Object p1, Object p2, boolean b) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState, this.GUI_ACTIONBAR_HEIGHT==0?R.layout.activity_funq_play_noactionbar:R.layout.activity_funq_play, true);
}
```

This workaround works only in non static methods.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, however my use case is one "Configuration" class that holds different final booleans, so I configure a lot of application-wide tweaks in one centralized place!